# Set Window Size according to system Resolustion

Tags: oracle, size, screen, resolution, oracleforms

I am designing an application using Oracle FORM Builder 6i. 
How can I change the window size that open automatically according to the monitor of various sizes?
Please help

Answer (score 1):

Locate window name in Object navigator; by default, it is (probably) "WINDOW1".

If `PRE-FORM` trigger doesn't exist, create it and put such a line into it:

```
set_window_property('WINDOW1', window_state, maximize);
                     -------
                     this is the window name
```

An alternative approach would be to use

```
set_window_property(forms_mdi_window, window_state, maximize);
```

Comment: when testing on different screen size, the problem is the same